# Docker Jenkins on Synology

Tags: docker, jenkins, synology

I have setup a docker-container for jenkins (name: jenkins-01) on my Synology NAS.
I also have setup the git-server provided by Synology on the same NAS.
To access the git-repositories from jenkins-01 I created a user "jenkins" on the NAS.

My git-server on the NAS is accessible by SSH and I can access repositories from my desktop-machine.

This is an example of the URL I use:

```
ssh://jenkins@<ip>:<port>/volume1/gitrepos/<repo>
```

With that URL I can clone a  from my desktop-machine.
I also setup a docker container using the exact same docker-compose.yml-file as provided on my NAS on my desktop machine. Within that jenkins-instance I can create a pipline using the URL shown here without any problems. So basically I am sure that the URL and the SSH-credentials used are fine.

However when I try to do the same thing within the jenkins-instance running as docker container on my NAS, I can't get a connection to the same git-server using the URL. The message provided is that the URL is not valid. I also tried to replace the  by the gateway-ip configured in the jenkins-instance.

To find out the gateway-ip I used the following command on the NAS:

```
docker container inspect jenkins-01
```

This is the docker-compose.yml I use:

```
version : "3"

services:
  app:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk11
    container_name: jenkins-01
    privileged: true
    user: root
    networks:
      vlan_devnet:
        ipv4_address: 172.18.100.2
    ports:
      - 51080:8080
      - 51000:50000
    volumes:
      - ./jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - ./etc/resolv.conf:/etc/resolv.conf
    environment:
      JAVA_OPTS: -Duser.timezone=CET
    restart: unless-stopped
        
networks:
  vlan_devnet:
    external: true
```

What do I miss?

---

I never figured this out and I no longer bother because I now use GitEA as Git-Server instead of the Synology Git-Server.

GitEA also provides a nice WebUI and similar functionality as GitHub - a very nice OpenSource project.

Because of that I will close this

Comment: Did you end up figuring this out?

Comment: Not really. However there are some workaround, which I haven't tired out yet.
1. I can create another container for the Git-Server in the same net as jenkins
2. I can mount the repo-folder into the jenkins and access the git "locally" from inside the jenkins.

I propably will go with option 1 and get rid of the GIt-server of Synology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use now GitEA, so don't have to bother with the Synology Git-Server. I know this does not answer the original question - however it works for me.